# Edit an object's relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a many-to-many relationship between a `User` class and a `Role` class (**through** the join table `UserRole`). This is so I can make sections of my application offlimits to users without certain roles, and accessible to users with these roles. This is how am setting the roles in via a `User` class method:

```
def add_role(role)
    self.user_roles.build(role_id: Role.find_by(role: role).id )
end
```

So `user_312.add_role('general')` will add the role of `general` to `user_312`'s roles. (Note that this isn't the same as a state machine, because users can have many different roles at the same time.)

The only thing I'm finding difficult is how to make an interface to add roles to a user. Here's my `user#edit` action and its resulting view:

*controller:*

```
def edit
    # maybe this should be a helper method?
    roles = Role.all

    @role_names = []

    roles.each do |role|
      @role_names << role.role
    end

end
```

*view:*

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    Current Roles: <br>
    Add Roles: <br>

  <%= f.label :roles %><br>
  <%= f.select :roles, @role_names   %>   

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div> 

<% end %>
```

This gives me a nice dropdown with all the role names, **but I have no idea what to put in my `user#update` action to create the selected relationship:**

```
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

So what should I do in this update action?

Comment: There isn't such a thing as a `has_many` `has_many` relationship. do you mean `has_and_belongs_to_many` ? If so - I'd google "Rails HABTM forms" to look for solutions. Lots of people have worked on this problem - so you don't have to reinvent the solution.

Comment: They both `have_many` through `user_roles` ( I didn't mention the join table, thought it would be inferred! Editing... )

Comment: nup - that wasn't clear, because you didn't use the magic word `through` ;) so I was envisioning somebody who didn't understand that you couldn't just jam two `has_many`s together... (which it turns out is not the case... but could have been) ;)

Comment: Yeah fair point :) Is the HABTM form still relevant here?

Comment: Possibly... it will behave in a similar way. Plus you might get some clues about how to take the inputs and update your model in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

[Refactor] You'd be better using the [`<<` ActiveRecord method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) to set the `roles` for your `user`:

```
def add_role(role)
    new_role = Role.find_by role: role
    current_user.roles << new_role
end
```

---

After reading the entire question, here's what I'd do (very simply):

```
#app/views/users/roles.html.erb
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

  <div class="field">
    Current Roles: <br>
    Add Roles: <br>

  <%= f.label :roles %><br>
  <%= f.collection_select :roles, Role.all, :id, :role, prompt: true

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div> 

<% end %>

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def update
    roles = params[:user][:roles]
    if roles.any?
        roles = Role.find(roles)
        current_user.roles << roles
    end
end
```

There are some more elements you will benefit from, but this is where I'd start